# Ruby gem Diffy not returning differences

Tags: ruby, rubygems, string-comparison, easyhtmlreport

I need to compare two xml files and display the differences in a html report. In order to do this, I installed the ruby gem Diffy (and the gems rspec and diff-lcs as directed by the Diffy documentation), but it does not seem to be working properly as differences are not being returned.

I have two xmls files I want to compare.

Xml file one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SourceDetails>
    <Origin>Origin</Origin>
    <Identifier>Identifier</Identifier>
    <Timestamp>2001-12-31T12:00:00</Timestamp>
  </SourceDetails>
  <AsOfDate>2001-01-01</AsOfDate>
  <Instrument>
    <ASXExchangeSecurityIdentifier>ASX</ASXExchangeSecurityIdentifier>
  </Instrument>
  <Rate>0.0</Rate>
```

Xml file two:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SourceDetails>
        <Origin>FEED</Origin>
        <Identifier>IR</Identifier>
        <Timestamp>2017-01-01T02:11:01Z</Timestamp>
    </SourceDetails>
    <AsOfDate>2017-01-02</AsOfDate>
    <Instrument>
        <CommonCode>GB0</CommonCode>
    </Instrument>
    <Rate>0.69</Rate>
```

When I supply the two xml files as arguments to the diffy function:

```
puts Diffy::Diff.new('xmldoc1', 'xmldoc2', :source => 'files').to_s(:html)
```

no differences are returned. When I store the two xml files in String variables and supply these variables as arguments to the Diffy function:

```
puts Diffy::Diff.new(doc1, doc2, :include_plus_and_minus_in_html => true).to_s(:html)
```

again no differences are returned. To figure out if my xmls were causing the problem, I also tried supplying two different strings to the Diffy function:

```
puts Diffy::Diff.new("Hello how are you", "Hello how are you\nI'm fine\nThat's great\n")
```

but this also returned nothing when there are clear differences.

Does anyone know what the problem may be?

Comment: So the Diffy gem is not working properly. What version are you using?

Comment: I am using version 3.2.1.

Comment: @SebastianPalma thank you so much for your comment. This prompted me to uninstall version 3.2.1 of Diffy and try 3.2.0 and it is working. Thank you so much for your guidance.

Comment: You're welcome. Just I tried with the same version you pointed and it worked, so I was unable to give you a certain answer. Glad it helped.